# Какой частью речи считать слово "частично" и обособляется ли оно запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что это вводное слово. Тогда его нужно выделять запятой. А  в данном случае понять не могу. Подскажите, пожалуйста!
Частично этот новый феномен объясняется тем простым фактом, что мы стали жить дольше и лучше; а частично это связано с тем, что...

Comment: Благодарю за ответы! Интуитивно я почувствовала правильно, но правила уже подзабыла. Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: А вот слово "отчасти" - вводное?

Comment: Тоже наречие, обстоятельство, не вводное.

Answer (score 2):

Вводные слова составляют второй план речи: они выражают  не содержание, а отношение автора к содержанию, различные оценочные суждения, а также используются для оформления речи.  Интересно то, что для проверки вводного слова его можно заменить синонимом.

Наречие "частично" похоже на вводное слово, так как имеет оценочное значение, но оно всегда входит в основное сообщение, где является обстоятельством (в роли вводного слова не замечено). Если его убрать, то нарушится  структура и смысл предложения.

Для сравнения: слово "в частности" является вводным: "Он, в частности (= к примеру), вполне подходит для этой роли". При этом структура предложения такова, что это слово удобно обособить. Но и тут есть одна тонкость: вводные слова могут использоваться для присоединения обособленных оборотов в качестве союзов, например: "Многие подходят для этой роли, в частности он".

Таким образом, одно и то же слово может в одном случае быть вводным словом, а в других - обстоятельством, союзом, частицей.

Comment: Одно и то же слово? Но Вы же их два назвали...

Answer (score 1):

Объясняется как? частично - наречие, обстоятельство образа действия, запятая не нужна.

Связано как? частично - то же самое, запятая не нужна.

Вводные слова не являются членами предложения, а это - обстоятельство, Значит, не вводное.